# Basic Variable Isolation

Tags: exponential-function

I'm trying to Isolate DR in the function below. Was wondering if I got it correct.

$(1 + DR)^y$ = $(1 + N/C)^C$

My answer

$$Dr = e^{\ln(1 + N/C)^C \over y}$$

Sorry about that last line. eveyrthing in the bracket after exponential is making the exponential raised by that.

Comment: Raise both sides to the power $\frac{1}{y}$ and you are almost finished. No log stuff needed.

Comment: Is this a typo? "Nint" instead of "N"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$(1+DR)^y = \left(1+\tfrac NC\right)^C$$
then
$$DR = \left(1+\tfrac NC\right)^{\frac Cy} - 1$$